# Adding arrows between the lines

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am using this code to draw a diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) rectangle (11,7);
\draw (1.5,6) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$}  .. controls (8,6) and (6,3) .. (10,3) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
\draw (1.5,4) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$}  .. controls (6,4) and (8.5,7) .. (10,6.5) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
\draw (1.5,2) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$}  .. controls (10,2) and (10,1.5) .. (10,1.5) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
\draw (10,5.5) node{\textbf{X}$^{-}$}  .. controls (6,5) and (11,4) .. (10,4) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
\draw (1.5,-0.3) node{$\tau$}  .. controls (3,0) and (11,-0.6) .. (10,-0.3) node{$\tau^{'}$};
\draw (12,7) node{$D_A\phi=0$};
\draw (12,-0.3) node{$\wedge^{+}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to draw arrows pointing left to right in the middle of each lines. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You mean perpendicular to the paths? Or relative to the rectangle?

Comment: Can you make your code fragment compilable. But apart from that, I'm not sure what you mean "pointing left to right in the middle".

Comment: @Alenanno I mean arrow sign only on the paths pointing the directions of the paths, not on the rectangles. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7d0U.png)?

Comment: @Alenanno No, parallel to the paths

Comment: Just the arrowheads on the paths

Comment: Well, the only other possibilty is [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO1Y1.png), then.

Comment: @Alenanno, yeah exactly. Thanks a lot. Can you please mention the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use decorations via the `decorations.markings` library.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    direc/.style={%
        postaction={decorate,
            decoration={%
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.5 with{%
                    \arrow{Straight Barb[scale=1.5]}
                },
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,1) rectangle (11,7);
    \draw[direc] (1.5,6) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$}  .. controls (8,6) and (6,3) .. (10,3) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
    \draw[direc] (1.5,4) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$}  .. controls (6,4) and (8.5,7) .. (10,6.5) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
    \draw[direc] (1.5,2) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$}  .. controls (10,2) and (10,1.5) .. (10,1.5) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
    \draw[direc] (10,5.5) node{\textbf{X}$^{-}$}  .. controls (6,5) and (11,4) .. (10,4) node{\textbf{X}$^{+}$};
    \draw[direc] (1.5,-0.3) node{$\tau$}  .. controls (3,0) and (11,-0.6) .. (10,-0.3) node{$\tau^{'}$};
    \draw (12,7) node{$D_A\phi=0$};
    \draw (12,-0.3) node{$\wedge^{+}$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Larsson no problem! :)